# Método POST enviando un Json String en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, json, http-post

Estoy intentando utilizar el método `POST` que contiene varios Objetos, ya intenté con algunas librerías pero no inserta nada, se me ocurre enviarlo cómo texto ya que usando `postman` si ingresa todos los datos a mi tabla.

```
{ "tableName": "nombre",   "payload": {
    "Item": {
      "Usuario": "123",
      "Contrasenia": "123",
      "Edad": "19"
    } }}
```

Les dejo mi método que estoy usando con `Volley`, cuando lo ejecuto me dice que si hay conexión pero no inserta ningún dato.

```
public void enviarDatos(){
        String url ="https://.../addUser";

        try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final org.json.JSONObject jsonBody = new org.json.JSONObject();


            jsonBody.put("tableName","nombre");
            jsonBody.put("Usuario","123");
            jsonBody.put("Contrasenia","123");
            jsonBody.put("Edad","19");

        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG,"satisfactorio:"+response);
                Log.d(TAG,"satisfactorio:"+jsonBody.toString());


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG,"fallo update"+error);


            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el código veo que estás tratando de hacer un StringRequest para mandar un JSON cuando realmente deberías usar `JsonObjectRequest`.

La firma del mismo es:

```
public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

por lo que en tu caso quedaría algo como:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // hazle un print al object o lo que gustes
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

luego solo añades el request al queue de volley

```
requestQueue.add(request);
```

Te recomiendo leer este [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) de la documentación oficial de Android.

Comment: Estimado Ivan muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo!! ya quedo resuelto el problema...